# Using epoch as time series on x axis in react-chartjs-2 not showing correct date

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am trying to make a dashboard with a time series plot with time on the x axis. I have got my date in an epoch format such as:

```
return {
      labels: [1568160683.5443,1568161754.43038,1568162825.31646,1568163896.20253, .......]
```

I have then arranged the options of my chart as such:

```
  xAxes: [
        {
          barPercentage: 1.6,
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            color: "rgba(29,140,248,0.1)",
            zeroLineColor: "transparent"
          },
          ticks: {
            padding: 20,
            fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
          },
          type: 'time',
          distrubution: 'linear',
          time: {
          displayFormats: {
          'millisecond': 'h:mm a',
          'second': 'h:mm a',
          'minute': 'h:mm a',
          'hour': 'h:mm a',
          'day': 'h:mm a',
          'week': 'h:mm a',
          'month': 'h:mm a',
          'quarter': 'h:mm a',
          'year': 'h:mm a'
        },
        }
        }
      ]
```

I have read that js epoch parsing will require the epoch to be in milliseconds, I have tried multiplying the epoch by 1000 to get in milliseconds, but my ouptput in my chart is still wrong. When using a web epoch converter my date comes out as "Wednesday, 11 September 2019 00:11:23.544" which is the correct value but in the chart it displays the date as Jan 1970 as seen below:

[image: Chart Output]

Whatever I try, the date comes out as 1970. Is there a simple fix that I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

As you wrote, "multiplying the epoch by 1000 to get milliseconds" should do the trick.

I made a runnable snippet out of the few epoch values you provided. The relevant line is the following:

```
labels: epochs.map(e => e * 1000),
```

To me, the result looks fine.

```js
const epochs = [1568160683.5443,1568161754.43038,1568162825.31646,1568163896.20253];
const values = [2, 3, 1, 2];

var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: epochs.map(e => e * 1000),
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My Dataset',
            data: values,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'red',
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'minute'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! For some reason couldn't get my labels array to map properly!